# Devices on WLAN and devices on LAN can't ping each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, ping

I'm trying to ping a laptop connected to a router via wifi from a pc connected to the router via ethernet.

-The devices both return "destination host unreachable".
-Both devices can ping the router and the router can ping both devices.
-The laptop can ping other devices connected through wifi when its connected through wifi as well, but when switched to ethernet, its not able to ping them anymore.

Both devices are on the same subnet.
Any thoughts on what the problem is?

Edit: My router is ZTE F660RV1

Comment: What model of router? Some routers put Ethernet and WiFi on different subnets within the same box.

Comment: Just added the model.

Comment: Normally it should not matter how you connect (wired or wireless) . Try updating the router firmware

Comment: @John Except when wireless isolation is enabled ... then it does matter

Comment: Interesting. I do not use Wireless Isolation on routers.

Comment: @TheLegendWeeb Make sure LAN/WiFi Isolation is **not** enabled on the Port Isolation screen - http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/ZTE/F660/Port_Isolation.htm

Comment: @TheLegendWeeb  - Default for this setting is "off" on my router (different than yours) but do check.

Comment: Oh,I wasn't aware this option existed. The router is locked by the ISP and I only got the user acccount. I'll see what I can do with the ISP or if I can put it in bridge. Thank you very much!