# Can't ping wireless connection to wired connection / can't do network shares

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ping

I can't ping WiFi to LAN / LAN to WiFi and can't do network shares (filesharing)

1. PC connect to Router(ONT) via Wired LAN

   ```
   IP Address      : 192.168.1.2
   Subnet Mask     : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway : 192.168.1.1
   ```
2. Notebook connect to Router(ONT) via WiFi

   ```
   IP Address      : 192.168.1.4
   Subnet Mask     : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway : 192.168.1.1
   ```
3. Router(ONT) = ZTE F609 IP Address : `192.168.1.1`

Reply from `192.168.1.2`: `Destination Host Unreachable`

I can't ping wireless to wired but can ping wireless to wireless.  If I can't ping, I can't do file sharing, as I need to share `folder/printer`.

Comment: It's likely whatever device isn't able to be pinged has a firewall rule blocking inbound ICMP `echo-request`

Comment: @JW0914 How to unlocking ICMP? 
i already do in cmd
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow

Comment: @JW0914 i can't access network shares.

Comment: @JW0914 which IP i must obscured?

Comment: Any non-[RFC1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918#section-3) IP (IP beginning `139`). _(Please place monospaced code within a `code box` - place a backtick at beginning & end of the command in a comment - see help to the bottom right of the comment box)_. You may also need to allow outbound ICMP Type 0 (`echo-reply`).  If that doesn't work, you'll need to review the device's firewall log to see where the traffic is being blocked.  For the share issue, please create a new question for it _(I'd also recommend doing a quick search on SuperUser to see if you find anything that can help)_.

Comment: A lot of router also disallow by default network communication among each other if the source is on Wifi. Therefore you should also check your router settings.

Comment: @Robert is spot on with client isolation for WLAN.  Also see [Devices on WLAN and devices on LAN can't ping each other](https://superuser.com/q/1489533/529800)

Comment: @JW0914 WLAN isolation already uncheck, but still can't ping

Comment: @Gwenilwyn As I previously mentioned, you're going to have to review the firewall logs on the device to determine where and why this is being blocked.

Comment: @JW0914 i know the answer, my router firmware locked isolation. but i dont know how to unlock it